# Disabling bed level before each print

Tags: bed-leveling

I am running SKR Mini E3V3 on my Ender 3 Pro with CR Touch. I'd like to stop the bed leveling before every print and to use the stored Mesh (UBL). Where and how do I do this? Do I need to do it in the firmware and Cura?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can disable the bed leveling procedure, just make sure to comment out the `G29` G-code and put the `M420 S` in after `G28` in your start G-code.

From the [Marlin documentation](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M420.html) you can read:

> Get and/or set bed leveling state. For mesh-based leveling systems use Z parameter to set the Z Fade Height.
>
> With `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_UBL` you can use L to load a mesh from EEPROM.
> Option `L` followed by an integer (`M420 L<int>`) -> Load mesh from EEPROM index (Requires `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_UBL` and `EEPROM_SETTINGS` defined in firmware)

Also note that

> - `G28` disables bed leveling. Follow with `M420 S` to turn leveling on, or use `RESTORE_LEVELING_AFTER_G28` to automatically keep leveling on after `G28`.

This implies that if `RESTORE_LEVELING_AFTER_G28` is set in your firmware, you do not need the `M420 S` command.

You can test this by removing `G29` in a current print, if you don't see the Z stepper move during the first layer, the `RESTORE_LEVELING_AFTER_G28` is not defined in firmware and you will need to use the `M420 S` command in your start G-code directly after `G28`.